# Не устанавливается модуль PyAudio

Tags: python, pyaudio

Пишу: pip install PyAudio, вроде начинается установка,
потом выводится следующая ошибка:
`ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: command: 'c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Wondershare\\CreatorTemp\\pip-install-76ozggur\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Wondershare\\CreatorTemp\\pip-install-76ozggur\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-record-4div5j4r\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Include\PyAudio' cwd: C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-install-76ozggur\pyaudio\ Complete output (9 lines): running install running build running build_py creating build creating build\lib.win32-3.8 copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8 running build_ext building '_portaudio' extension error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/ ---------------------------------------- ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Wondershare\\CreatorTemp\\pip-install-76ozggur\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Wondershare\\CreatorTemp\\pip-install-76ozggur\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-record-4div5j4r\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Include\PyAudio' Check the logs for full command output.`

У меня Python (3.8.5)

Comment: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

Comment: @nörbörnën, то есть надо Visual Studio Community скачать?

Comment: да, с некоторыми нюансами https://stackoverflow.com/a/49984619/4496422

Comment: @nörbörnën, Спасибо